# Why is my some CSS formatting in a linked style sheet in not applied?

Tags: html, css, formatting, html5-video

I am trying to add a Youtube video in my page using a CSS style sheet to my page, for some reason, video is not appearing

```css
.youtube-video iframe,
.youtube-video img,
.youtube-video-2 iframe,
.youtube-video-2 img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 12%;
    width: 890px;
    height: 500px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<img class=" ls-is-cached lazyloaded" data-src="https://supertasker.pk/images/youtube-video-1-min-new.png" alt="Youtube-vide" video-url="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-luUppOIWHA" src="https://supertasker.pk/images/youtube-video-1-min-new.png">
```

Comment: This looks like you need JS in order to trigger the youtube video as the <img tag has no standard attribute of video-url

Answer (score 0):

```css
.youtube-video iframe,
.youtube-video img,
.youtube-video-2 iframe,
.youtube-video-2 img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 12%;
    width: 890px;
    height: 500px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
```

this will now run here as it is blocked from this site.
but you can check it working here:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_youtubeiframe